# MongoDB Node.js Script Implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently using the mongodb driver for node.js in a web project. I found the basic functions through w3schools and the mongo docs. But I haven't found a javascript method for validation, and the only way that I can't do it right now is through the mongo shell in cmd. Is there a function to write raw code in a js so that mongo can execute it like a script? That would save a lot of time having to deal with complex validations in console.

Comment: What are you trying to validate?

Comment: I'm validating schemas using the validator function for mongodb shell, using validator and $jsonSchema. I'm able to do it through command line, but I wanted to see if there was a higher level implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest looking into [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) npm module.  Mongoose npm module has a lot of useful features that interact with MongoDB.  You mentioned validating the data, which [could also be found here.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).  As you are setting up schemas in Mongoose, you have the option to provide in-built validation methods.

*Note* this code is pulled from the validation page of mongoosejs.com

```
var breakfastSchema = new Schema({
    eggs: {
         type: Number,
         min: [6, 'Too few eggs'],
         max: 12
    },
    bacon: {
         type: Number,
         required: [true, 'Why no bacon?']
    },
    drink: {
         type: String,
         enum: ['Coffee', 'Tea'],
         required: function() {
             return this.bacon > 3;
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I could be mistaken but I thought mongoose schemas only validate against themselves. I will keep on reading to see if I can do it with mongoose. What I want is to make use of the validator command for $jsonschema for mongo, 'cause that modifies the collection schema in mongo itself, and it's what I've been doing through mongo shell in cmd. Ty for your answer!

Comment: Mongoose docs say it's all middleware. Link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: @DavidCristerna so you are looking for a stand alone object to validate other objects?  You could just try what you are doing in the terminal, but just with the [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) library from npm.  Or you could use Joi as another user mentioned in combination with the mongodb library or mongoose libarary.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like what you are looking for is *Stored JavaScript*. While they are not equivalent, you can think of it almost like a *Stored Procedure* in SQL. [Here](http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html) is a good introduction to *Stored JavaScript*.

Comment: Not quite, but I will look into it too. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for validating the objects then you can use [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) library.

Comment: Not quite, but I will look into it too. Thanks for your answer!